# Google Cloud Speech API on production

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

As we know, `Google Cloud Speech API` is in Beta now.

Will it be safe to use it in a application on production server?

I was also searching for the applications which is using `Google Cloud Speech API`, So far I have found the following,
`VoiceBase`, `Hyperconnect`, `InterActiveTel`

Does anyone know of any other applications that could give us more confidence in using it on production server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official definition of GCP launch stages, such as Beta, can be found in our [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/terms/launch-stages).

> Beta is the point at which we are ready to open a release for any customer to use. There are no SLA or technical support obligations in a Beta release, and charges may be waived in some cases. Products will be complete from a feature perspective, but may have some open outstanding issues. Beta releases are suitable for **limited production** use cases.

Emphasis is mine: Limited production. Ultimately, it is going to come down to your risk appetite.

Answer (score 2):

[As of Tuesday, April 18](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/04/Cloud-Speech-API-is-now-generally-available.html), the Cloud Speech API has reached General Availability, meaning all features are open to developers and are to be considered stable.

Answer (score 0):

Voicebase provides more than just speech recognition and it is currently used in production by large customers. Take a look at some of the features

http://voicebase.readthedocs.io/en/v2-beta/index.html

Comment: For Voicebase V3 API, refer to https://voicebase.readthedocs.io/en/v3/how-to-guides/swagger-codegen.html